# Hashmap returns null only on the first try

Tags: java, sockets, nullpointerexception, hashmap, try-catch

I'm writing a simple file server that will let the user telnet in, supply a username and search for the access level given to that user, and then show a list of files and only allow them to see the contents of the file if they have a sufficient access level.  This code is for the server side, I'm just using PuTTY for the client

I read the userfile in (delimited with colons to separate name and access level)

```
paul:10
schemm:8
bobbarker:0
```

with this code

```
static Map<String, Integer> users = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
file = new File("userfile.txt");
try
{
    out.println("Reading userfile.txt");
    Scanner scannerusers = new Scanner(file);

    while (scannerusers.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        String line = scannerusers.nextLine();
        line.trim();
        String field[] = line.split(":");

        users.put(field[0], Integer.parseInt(field[1]));
    }
    scannerusers.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    out.println("userfile.txt not found!");
}
```

But my actual problem is here (at least I think).  Both the uncommented and commented code will fail on the first attempt, but succeed on the second.

```
//socket connection stuff here, and all this is nested in a try-catch to get 
//connection errors

while(!check)
{
    outToClient.writeBytes("What is your username?");
    clientinput = inFromClient.readLine();
    String username = clientinput;

    //                          
    if(users.get(username) == null)
    {
        outToClient.writeBytes("Invalid username");
    }
    else
    {
        check = true;
    }
    //

    //try
    //{
    //    accesslevel = users.get(username);
    //    check = true; //my thinking was that the NullPointerException would be thrown
    //                  //before this point, but either way doesn't fix the problem
    //}
    //catch(NullPointerException e)
    //{
    //  outToClient.writeBytes("Incorrect username");
    //}
}
```

Edit:  I put the full source on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/KuEZ4HyU)

Comment: Could you have a race condition? Where the map is being looked up *before* it's fully loaded?

Comment: What is `inFromClient` and are you sure the line it is reading is the string you expect? Have you printed it out? Perhaps there is some junk prepended to it the first time around?

Comment: inFromClient is just a buffered reader

Comment: Try debugging the code with a checkpoint in that condition. One of these is happening: either the username you think you are querying is not the one that is actually being queried, or the map doesn't have that username for some reason (maybe there's some spaces you're not seeing?)

Comment: This isn't the issue, but just so you know:  `line.trim()` doesn't actually modify `line` (Strings are immutable), it returns the result.  You want to do `line = line.trim();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, this does sound like a race condition but I don't see where a race condition would come from in your code. Perhaps it's the way you open your streams? Now I haven't played with Java in a while, but if I remember right I always had the base stream, then opened an input stream reader (I think) from the base stream, then wrapped a buffered reader around that.

Try printing out the string you receive from the client, in ASCII codes. Printing out the actual string might not show some unprintable characters you might be receiving.

Comment: Ah, there we go.  PuTTY returns ÿûÿû ÿûÿû'ÿýÿûÿýpaul the first time, then paul the second time I try.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it ALWAYS fails the first time, and ALWAYS succeeds the second, then it sounds like a race condition. Perhaps the file read code is triggered by the first read operation, but done in a separate thread so the calling thread continues instead of synchronously waiting for the result. We need to see the calling code to be sure.

Comment: All of the code is in main, and in the order I posted it.  I left some stuff out, the try-catch with an IOException is inside of a while(true) as well.  Here's the whole kit and kaboodle, with my dumb debug stuff left in.  http://pastebin.com/KuEZ4HyU

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `inFromClient.readLine()` is reading more (or less) than you expect the first time around. Are you sure it is returning what you expect? I haven't used PuTTY in a while, perhaps it is sending some terminal control characters on initial connect that are getting picked up by your first read? You also don't show us the connection code, are you sending data back and forth prior to this point that is not being fully processed?

Comment: Ah, there we go.  PuTTY returns ÿûÿû ÿûÿû'ÿýÿûÿýpaul the first time, then paul the second time I try.  Thank you!